# Requiring a Publisher with a current value

Tags: combine

Both `CurrentValueSubject` and `@Published.Publisher` (retrieved via $ from an ObservableObject property) immediately send a notification with the current value when a new subscriber is added (verified with this [example](https://github.com/ralfebert/CombinePublisherBehaviour/blob/main/CombinePublisherBehaviour/CombinePublisherBehaviourView.swift)).

Is there a way to require this behaviour with a protocol?

For example, if you offer an initializer that requires to pass a publisher, one would use `AnyPublisher` here:

```swift
init(settings: AnyPublisher<Settings, Never>) {
    // ...
}
```

This would allow to be sneaky and pass in a `PassthroughSubject` erased to `AnyPublisher`. Is there a way to prevent this that would allow to pass in both a `CurrentValueSubject` or an `@Published` property? (something like a `AnyValuePublisher`?)

Comment: To *require this behaviour* for sure, the only possible way, under full control, is to have factory that generates private opaque publishers (as final class or struct). In such case it will not be possible to substitute them with anything else by interface contract and will be validated by swift compiler. Btw Apple often use something like this in their APIs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know up-ahead which `Publisher` will replay its latest value vs. which will not (since a custom publisher could do the same, too).

The only thing I can think of in this specific use case is a ghost protocol to only mark these two types for this use case:

```swift
protocol ReplayingPublisher: Publisher {}

extension CurrentValueSubject: ReplayingPublisher {}
extension Published.Publisher: ReplayingPublisher {}

struct MyObject {
    init<P: ReplayingPublisher>(publisher: P) {
        // P is only one of these two possible options
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... who forbids me to confirm PassthroughSubject to ReplayingPublisher and use it as input for MyObject?

Comment: Obviously no one, no one forbids you from passing a `Int` conforming to this protocol :) Limitations like this are made to make a developer's life easier. If someone wants to "go around it", you can do so with most variations.

Answer (score 2):

Below you will find implementation that is what you are looking for:

```swift
// MARK: - ValuePublisher

public protocol ValuePublisher: Publisher {
    var value: Output { get }
}

// MARK: - AnyValuePublisher

public struct AnyValuePublisher<Output, Failure>: ValuePublisher where Failure: Error {

    nonisolated public var value: Output {
        box.value
    }

    private let box: PublisherBoxBase<Output, Failure>

    public init<T: ValuePublisher>(_ valuePublisher: T) where T.Output == Output, T.Failure == Failure {

        if let erased = valuePublisher as? AnyValuePublisher<Output, Failure> {
            self.box = erased.box
        } else {
            self.box = PublisherBox(base: valuePublisher)
        }
    }

    nonisolated public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        box.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
}

// MARK: - AnyValuePublisher > PublisherBox

extension AnyValuePublisher {
    private class PublisherBoxBase<Output, Failure: Error>: ValuePublisher {
        internal var value: Output {
            fatalError("abstract method")
        }

        internal init() {}

        internal func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream)
            where Failure == Downstream.Failure, Output == Downstream.Input {
            fatalError("abstract method")
        }
    }

    private final class PublisherBox<PublisherType: ValuePublisher>: PublisherBoxBase<PublisherType.Output, PublisherType.Failure> {
        internal let base: PublisherType

        internal override var value: PublisherType.Output {
            base.value
        }

        internal init(base: PublisherType) {
            self.base = base
        }

        internal override func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Failure == Downstream.Failure, Output == Downstream.Input {
            base.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}

extension Publisher where Self: ValuePublisher {
    public func eraseToAnyValuePublisher() -> AnyValuePublisher<Output, Failure> {
        AnyValuePublisher(self)
    }
}

extension CurrentValueSubject: ValuePublisher {}
```

Sample usage would be:

```swift
let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(1).eraseToAnyValuePublisher()
let someValue: Int = publisher.value
```

Comment: This is a great solution if we want to rely on path ways that separate value publishers to any publishers. One thing to consider is that you can have auto-updating values with AnyPublisher. So although a good solution, I don't see an architectural use case for something like this.

Comment: Thanks, we have usecase in our app that’s why i created it. We are using it in our MVVM where ViewModel is an actor, and we need to have nonisolated let publisher where value is thread-safe and can be accesed from ViewController which is MainActor and changed from ViewModel from actor (which is background thread)

Comment: I solved the same problem by having one single update path for state that has a GDC queue barrier. Making a view model an actor created unnecessary complexity. I am finding actors are good for highly concurrent systems. But the work most apps do isn't really needed. I can imagine video games could possibly need it, but apps running networking code, I have yet to run into a need for actors. Most work happens in background threads then filters into one funnel for state updates. Easier to write code and does the job.

Comment: Also, checkout Asynchrone by Red Davis. He's created an entire suite of tools for turning much of the Combine pieces into Async/Await and they are so far a great solution.

Comment: I know it and i am even contributor, but Async/Await streams has some disadvantages

Comment: As an update to this, we cannot use .map on the AnyValuePublisher, I would be interested to know if you had someone implement all of the extensions for this with Publisher, because there's a lot there.

Comment: extension Publishers.Map: ValuePublisher where Upstream: ValuePublisher {
    public var value: Output {
        transform(upstream.value)
    }
}

Comment: We actually decided to approach the problem differently. Identified that there was a thread switch going on when state changes. So now all state updates happen on the main thread. Instead of using .receive(on: ) with our calls. The main core state update does a dispatch on the main thread when updating the main value subject of our app state. So the actual values are now pushed into the UI on the same frame as they are assigned. In this case, we no longer needed the current value subject. Thanks very much Michal. Respect for your knowledge of combine. It's sad apple have dropped it really. :/